# Blender 2.8 Texture Paint Nodes - supported in Unity?

Tags: node-editor, texture-painting, unity

I know node-based mats are not supported in unity.

However, texture painted mats are supported in unity.

Now, 2.8 blurs the lines because it allows node-based mats to be created in texture painting.  Is the result of this maintained if you export to Unity please?

Thanks,

A

Answer (score 2):

In general, node logic is specific to Blender and will not be supported in other software. Material and texture creating in far from standardised across technologies, and thus trying to match and support it is just about impossible. In certain cases, certain exporters may detect similar nodes and try and recreate them in the target format/application (for example in the case of fbx export, 2.8 uses the principled shader for basic material settings), however this is the exception, not the rule.

The solution for exporting generated textures to any other program is to bake them to an image file.

Comment: So Unity takes a height map, bump (normal) map, diffuse (albedo) map and roughness (smooth) map.  All of this can be created in 2.8.  The question isn't whether or not an image file needs to be created (it does), but whether the workflow will transfer.   

If it *does* transfer, then does (for example) the bump node that allows joint creation of diffuse (albedo) and bump (normal) *also* transfer?  Because if so, that's a major step forward.